# Building Day Over Day logic in SQL

Tags: sql

I have a calendar based table in SQL, if I have date as 24-03-2013, I have all information regarding it. Day, week no., Month in words, Quarter no. and so on.

Now I want to get same information for same date but for previous year, that is, 24-03-2012.

Kind of Day over Day concept.

Schema,

```
 DateKey| DayName  |DayOfWeek|DayOfMonth|DayOfYear|WeekOfMonth|WeekOfYear|MonthName|MonthofYear|QuarterNum|YearNum|LeapYearFlag

19000101|01-01-1900|    2    |    1     |    1    |     0     |    1     | January |     1     |    1     |  1900  |   0

20050101|01-01-2005|    7    |    1     |    1    |     0     |    1     | January |     1     |    1     |  2005  |   0

20050102|01-02-2005|    1    |    2     |    2    |     0     |    1     | January |     1     |    1     |  2005  |   0
```

Comment: So what is the issue here, exactly?

Comment: what did you try so far?

Comment: @Sachin Actually I am beginner in SQL. Don't know how to proceed. I can do it using Talend, but don't know about queries.

Comment: What is your database engine?  You mentioned sql, but that's a programming language.

Comment: Since you don't know about queries, I've heard good things about the book, Teach Yourself SQL in 10 Minutes.

Comment: Post the table schema and an example entry. Otherwise nobody can help you write a query.

Comment: Which RDBMS is this for? Please add a tag to specify whether you're using `mysql`, `postgresql`, `sql-server`, `oracle` or `db2` - or something else entirely.

Comment: Why do you want to store and query that? Usually it is cheaper to compute it using built-in functions...

Comment: @HenrikLoeser: A date dimension table is a fairly common feature of star schema datawarehouses; given the `DateKey` column, I guess that's what is happening here. It's particularly helpful if you want a row returned by a query for a date which has no matching transaction records, amongst other things.

Comment: @MarkBannister: Agree, but for designing/building a DWH you should have some background on SQL, performance, and database design.

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
declare @date datetime
select @date = '20120304'
select convert(varchar, @date, 112)as DateKey, 
datename(dw, @date)as DayName,
datepart(weekday, @date) as DayOfWeek, 
datepart(day, @date)as DayOfMonth , 
datepart(dayofyear, @date) as DayOfYear,
datepart(week, @date) as WeekOfYear, DATENAME(month, @date) as MonthName, datepart(month, @date)as MonthofYear,  datepart(quarter, @date)as QuarterNum, 
datepart(year, @date)as YearNum, CASE WHEN ISDATE( convert(varchar,datepart(year, @date)) + '0229')  = 1 THEN 0 ELSE 1 END as LeapYearFlag
```

Answer (score -1):

Following code should help in MSSQL to get the datetime format:

```
create table #temp
(
 name varchar(50)
)

insert into #temp values ('19000101|01-01-1900|2|1|1|0|1|January|1|1|1900|0')
insert into #temp values ('20050101|01-01-2005|7|1|1|0|1|January|1|1|2005|0')
insert into #temp values ('20050102|01-02-2005|1|2|2|0|1|January|1|1|2005|0')

select convert(datetime, SUBSTRING(name,0,charindex('|',name,0)), 103) from #temp
```

you can change the name of column and format as you wish.